# Avoid excessive rspec nesting with subject, let, and alternative arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to do some model_spec testing but having trouble with not having to further nest my rspec code. It would be great if in this case, I could just have a set of "it's" instead of having to add context everytime I want to switch the variable **var**. Here's the following code:

```
describe "#some_method" do

subject { course.some_method(var) }

context 'given a project' do

  let(:var) {random[1]}
  it 'returns the one after' do
    is_expected.to eq(random[2])
  end

  context 'being the last' do
    let(:vars) {random.last}
    it 'returns nil' do
      is_expected.to be_nil
    end
  end

  context '...you get the point, being something else' do
    let(:vars) { something.else }
    it 'returns nil' do
      is_expected.to.to be_nil
    end
  end

end
end
```

Maybe I'm just stuck in the wrong mode of thinking and someone could think of a better way for me to do this? I've been suggested that I absolutely must use the subject by someone I work for.

*At first, I disagreed and thought it was getting a little burdensome but then I figured keeping subject and having let(:var) apply to it was pretty useful...*

Comment: Maybe you should politely ask him to take his dogma and shove it. Sometimes subject can be used to write more succinct tests but being forced to always use it leads to awkward constructs and unreadable tests.

Comment: haha i dont know...i tried but im happy as long as we can just get this testing moving. im quite new to testing and its effects but it seems like there's just no simple, easy way to go about things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you write it like this?
`expect(subject.call(foo))` is not very pretty but it gets rid of the nesting.

```
describe "#some_method" do
  subject { course.method(:some_method) }

  it 'returns the one after if given a project' do
    expect(subject.call(random[1])).to eq(random[2])
  end

  it 'returns nil when it is the last' do
    expect(subject.call(random.last)).to be_nil
  end

  it 'returns nil...' do
    expect(subject.call(something.else)).to be_nil
  end
end
```

Comment: oo ill try that, thanks. ive been kinda out of ruby land for a while and havent fully used their flexibility with oop and manipulating methods.

Comment: While it does solve the problem in the question don't do this. Explicit subject calls on subject are regarded as poor practice and this makes for dismal readability just for the sake of dogma.

Comment: @maxcal thanks, i agree but that just heads back to my question of "what should i be doing?." even if i weren't using subject, the repetitive code for the sake of just changing the arguments would still exist. if i could use something like a proc object and pass subject as a method, that would be great but that unfortunately does not work.

Answer (score 1):

RSpecs subject is a tool which can be used to make tests more succinct. There are many cases where it makes sense to use the subject:

```
RSpec.describe User do
  # with the help of shoulda-matchers
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of :username } # implicit subject
end

RSpec.describe UsersController do

  describe '#show' do
    it 'is successful' do
       get :show
       expect(response).to have_http_status :success
    end
    it 'renders template show' do
       get :show
       expect(response).to render_template :show
    end
  end

  #vs 
  describe '#show' do
    subject { response }
    before { get :show }
    it { should have_http_status :success }
    it { should render_template :success }
  end      
end
```

And there are cases where using subject will hurt the readability and acuity of your tests.

Your college is just plain wrong in insisting that you always use subject.

A good rule of hand is that if you need an `it` block then you should not be using subject or `is_expected`.

If you are describing the call signature of a method you should be calling it in your specs in the same way you would in real life.

```
let(:decorator){ described_class.new(user) }

describe "#link" do
  it 'takes a class option' do
    expect(decorator.link(class: 'button')).to match /class=\"button/
  end
end
```

I would recommend running rspec with the `--format documentation` option and checking if the output actually makes sense. This can be quite important once you get 100s of specs as it gets harder to remember what a behavior a spec actually covers.

Comment: http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/blog/2012/05/13/spec-smell-explicit-use-of-subject/

Comment: just curious, do you know of any great, live project examples online. i wanna see something more than just the bare-bones plain ones. ive been searching now and then but havent found any yet.

Comment: thank you so much for this. gonna take a huge look at it when i have time